# Parsing Perforce File Specification Library

Tags: library, c#, c++, parser, perforce

Before I re-invent the wheel, I would like to know if anyone has previously created a library to parse and/or create a Perforce File Specification (http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html) in some library either in C++ or C#. I'd like to perform various operations like:

- Optimize client spec (remove unneeded -/+ that are superfluous) and sort it
- Create a client spec based on 'have' list
- Add/remove new directories or file lists

The motivation is to make managing client specs automatic through a front-end tool. There is a decent editor in P4V, but in most cases I can generate the client spec for people in my company to make things easier.

One example would be to pass in a client spec something like:

```
//depot/Release/HEAD/... //joel.van.eenwyk_dev/HEAD/...
-//depot/Release/HEAD/Test/... //joel.van.eenwyk_dev/HEAD/Test/...
-//depot/Release/HEAD/Docs/... //joel.van.eenwyk_dev/HEAD/Docs/...
//depot/Release/HEAD/Docs/... //joel.van.eenwyk_dev/HEAD/Docs/...
```

And it would automatically optimize it to:

```
//depot/Release/HEAD/... //joel.van.eenwyk_dev/HEAD/...
-//depot/Release/HEAD/Test/... //joel.van.eenwyk_dev/HEAD/Test/...
```

I'm looking for an open-source solution that does not cost anything. My target platform is Windows, but happy to port code over from other platforms.

Comment: Would you mind posting a short example file, just to make sure your question is extra-clear for everyone? Thanks!

Comment: Also, do you have any license or price preference? And is it OK for the library to rely on OS-specific things?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I added an example and my open source requirement.